# Angular 1.5 skip nav overridden by router

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular 1.5 app that needs to be accessible. I've added a skipnav i.e:

```
<a href="#content">Skip navigation</a>
```

however this is being overridden by:

```
$urlRouterProvider
  .otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {
    var state = $injector.get('$state');
    state.go('404');
    return $location.path();
  });
```

How can I set the focus on the #content area?

Comment: Is `content` a valid state in your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - The [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#otherwise-for-invalid-routes) states that the arameter is *The url path you want to redirect to or **a function rule that returns the url path**. The function version is passed two params: $injector and $location*.

So you're redirecting to the `404` state and return the **location path** which return only the current path without any parameters nor the hash.

What you need to do is to set the hash first (in case it's not already presented in the URL or the url contain a different hash):

```
$location.hash('content');
```

And then, return the absolute url with all segments:

```
return $location.absUrl();
```

There is a chance that you could just `return;` without returning any path, because just by setting `$location.absUrl()` will make angular focus the `#content` element. Not sure about it, but you can try and see if it's working for you.

Comment: Thanks! I had to check if the hash was 'content' and then set attributes based on https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/01/15/fixing-skip-to-content-links/ and seems to work now.